# Make the Home Tab the default page

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Every time I read and delete a message in the Inbox, Outlook 2010 goes to the File tab.
I want it to stay on the Home tab, but I've been unable to find any reliable method to do so.
Minimizing the ribbon and restarting Outlook will bring up the home Tab page. But as soon as 
I read and delete a message after maximizing the ribbon, it returns to the File page again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Excel. This is what worked for me:

1. Go to Home tab and right click to show the toolbar options.
2. Disable (uncheck) the minimize ribbon button.